# Got MySQL Error #1064 on a simple insert, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, insert, create-table

I need some help, I'm getting `error 1064` when I try to insert data into a table!

```
INSERT INTO areas (Nombre) values ('area 1');
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Areas (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Table name in insert query. Changed `areas` to `Areas`.

Comment: Please update your question with the OS you are using (Windows or Linux).

Comment: I think he is using Linux.

Comment: Your error message is inconsistent with what you have shown us in your question.  Is there any other information you might be leaving out which could explain the `1064` error?

Comment: The INSERT statement is fine, as long as the CREATE TABLE is run first. A duplicate key error would be `Error code: 1062`, a table doesn't exist error would be `Error code: 1146`. But you report that error code `1064` is being returned. That error usually includes a portion of the statement text, identifying the point in the statement text where MySQL detects syntax error. In its current form, this question is unanswerable. (You've not identified which client you are using to submit SQL to the database.)

Comment: @spencer7593 No need to vote everyone down across the board, as the owner of the question may return to give us more information.  But yeah, it feels pretty good to vote people down.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you used **areas** instead of **Areas**.

Comment: This won't matter if he's running Windows.

Comment: Yes it won't but it saves you the trouble if you develop using different OS.

Comment: He should be using lowercase table name _everywhere_ to avoid the issue entirely.  This would also make his MySQL code more portable between Windows and Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Your server configuration seems case sensitive so areas and Areas will be 2 tables.

try below-

```
INSERT INTO Areas (Nombre) VALUES ('area 1');
```

If you want to take care it then update below variable in your my.cnf or my.ini file.

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

Comment: @Mauro mentioned that he tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: If this was the problem, the more likely error would be "1146 Table doesn't exist".

Comment: @Mauro:first check if table exist by desc areas; if exist then again execute your insert statement and check what error you are getting.